# c : /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by c )

Tags: c++

I am starting with IGPROF for memory profiling--

i installed it and done all the steps defined in - http://igprof.sourceforge.net/install.html

but when i am running:

> c++ -o vvvi-build-and-copy vvvi-build-and-copy.cc -ldl -lpthread

i am getting error-

> c++: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by c++)

i google it but not getting what should i do?? i am using ubuntu right now.

Can you help me ?? plz tell me if you need any other info
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2):

It usually means that you are using library compiled by newer compiler (gcc) than you are currently running.  You need to recompile library with your current compiler or change to newer compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You do not say what version of Ubuntu. Anyway, the problem is caused by a glibc version mismatch between your C++ and the version installed in Ubuntu.

Run the command

```
/lib/libc.so.6
```

to get information on your system's glibc, to confirm. You will see something which is not "version 2.11" as your installed C++ requires.

Your situation may occur if you did an incomplete update of the distribution (i.e., glibc is older than C++ expects, because you forced an update to C++ but left glibc behind).

The best solution should be to do an "apt-get upgrade" of the "old" packages ("apt-get upgrade glibc"), or even update the whole distribution.

Note: this probably has nothing to do with `igprof` installation, which is unlikely to have modified C++, much less glibc.