# version `GLIBC_2.11' not found while using gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, glibc, libc

I have problem using gcc/g++ after I changed the machine I use,
I installed gcc-4.9.2 in my previous machine, when I moved to the new machine, I copied gcc folder to the new machine.

When I try to use I get this error :

```
/data/obenchek/gcc-4.9.2/bin/g++: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by /data/obenchek/gcc-4.9.2/bin/g++)
```

I have already checked this question : 
[`GLIBC_2.11' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317296/c-lib64-libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-11-not-found-required-by-c)

If it says right, the version of libc and g++ are not compatible , libc version :

```
/lib/libc.so.6                                            
GNU C Library stable release version 2.4 (20090904), by Roland McGrath et al.
...
```

So I should reinstall gcc completely or there is a easier way to resolve this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I copied gcc folder to the new machine.

That's your problem: don't copy, install appropriate GCC package instead.

Most UNIX systems, including Linux, guarantee backward compatibility: a binary compiled on an older system continues to run on a newer one.

The reverse is *not* true: a binary compiled on a newer system often will  *not* run on an older one. This is working "as designed".

In this particular instance, you copied GCC compiled with GLIBC-2.11 or newer to a machine that has GLIBC-2.10 or older. And that doesn't work.

Comment: The new machine has a newer version of GLIBC actually

Comment: @Othman No, it does not. It has GLIBC 2.4, which is much older than 2.11 that you need.